# PyQGIS - create a centroid point symbol layer via Geometry Generator on a polygon layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology, geometry-generator

I'm trying to created a Geometry Generator symbol layer (point) that creates centroids from `myLayer`, a polygon map layer. Sounds easy, right? Here is my code - I think I'm missing a line to declare that I want this symbol layer to have a point geometry, and possibly much more!

Here is my code so far - please let me know what I'm missing (or where I can find a resource to explain how I can build this code).

```
layerName = 'myLayer'
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]

generator = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
generator.setColor(QColor("blue"))
expression = 'centroid($geometry)'
generator.setGeometryExpression(expression)
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vLayer.geometryType())
generator.setSymbolType(symbol)
print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the snippet below. It works for me on a polygon layer styled with an existing simple fill symbol.

```py
layerName = 'myLayer'
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
ggsl = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
ggsl.setSymbolType(QgsSymbol.Marker)
ggsl.setGeometryExpression("centroid($geometry)")
ggsl.setColor(QColor('Blue'))
symbol = vLayer.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())[0]
symbol.insertSymbolLayer(1, ggsl)
vLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Result:

[image]

The `insertSymbolLayer()` method of the `QgsSymbolClass` takes 2 arguments- the index of the position at which the symbol layer should be inserted and a the symbol layer object to insert.

Quote from the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbol.html#a5ebdab8e197f23a9ff71dc1784e932f0):

> Parameters
>
> **index** The index at which the layer should be added
>
> **layer** The symbol layer to add

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! What is the integer in the first argument for **symbol.insertSymbolLayer()** - is that the layer order?

Comment: @grego, sorry for the delayed reply. Yes, the integer argument is the index at which to insert the symbol layer. I have updated my answer with a link to the docs.